# HQL Hibernate registerFunction FUNCTION does not exist

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, dialect

I'm trying to register a custom dialect in Hibernate.  I found a ton of examples, and I thought I had it - and now it tells me that the function does not exist in my database.  Specifically, I'm trying to create the date_add() dialect for MySQL 5.6.  I'm using hibernate 3.6.7.

In hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="dialect">com.myPackage.CustomMySQLDialect</property>    
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

In com.myPackage.CustomMySQLDialect:

```
public class CustomMySQLDialect extends MySQL5InnoDBDialect {

     public CustomMySQLDialect() {
          super();
          registerFunction( "date_add_interval", new SQLFunctionTemplate( Hibernate.DATE, "date_add(?1, interval ?2 ?3)" ) );
     }

}
```

And when I go to call it in the DAOImpl class:

```
List<User> userList = null;
            Query confirmationUser = session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from InitUser where enabled = 0 and date_add_interval(created_date, 1, day) < now() and end_date is null");

userList = confirmationUser.list();  // <-- this is where it dies
```

Here's the exception:

```
Hibernate: select inituser0_.init_user_id as init1_58_, inituser0_.confirmation_date as confirma2_58_, inituser0_.confirmation_sent_date as confirma3_58_, inituser0_.confirmation_token as confirma4_58_, inituser0_.created_date as created5_58_, inituser0_.current_sign_in_date as current6_58_, inituser0_.current_sign_in_ip as current7_58_, inituser0_.email as email58_, inituser0_.enabled as enabled58_, inituser0_.end_date as end10_58_, inituser0_.failed_sign_in_count as failed11_58_, inituser0_.last_sign_in_date as last12_58_, inituser0_.last_sign_in_ip as last13_58_, inituser0_.password as password58_, inituser0_.remember_created_date as remember15_58_, inituser0_.reset_password_confirmation_date as reset16_58_, inituser0_.reset_password_sent_date as reset17_58_, inituser0_.reset_password_token as reset18_58_, inituser0_.sign_in_count as sign19_58_, inituser0_.updated_by as updated20_58_, inituser0_.updated_date as updated21_58_, inituser0_.username as username58_ from InitUser inituser0_ where inituser0_.end_date is null
Hibernate: select inituser0_.init_user_id as init1_58_, inituser0_.confirmation_date as confirma2_58_, inituser0_.confirmation_sent_date as confirma3_58_, inituser0_.confirmation_token as confirma4_58_, inituser0_.created_date as created5_58_, inituser0_.current_sign_in_date as current6_58_, inituser0_.current_sign_in_ip as current7_58_, inituser0_.email as email58_, inituser0_.enabled as enabled58_, inituser0_.end_date as end10_58_, inituser0_.failed_sign_in_count as failed11_58_, inituser0_.last_sign_in_date as last12_58_, inituser0_.last_sign_in_ip as last13_58_, inituser0_.password as password58_, inituser0_.remember_created_date as remember15_58_, inituser0_.reset_password_confirmation_date as reset16_58_, inituser0_.reset_password_sent_date as reset17_58_, inituser0_.reset_password_token as reset18_58_, inituser0_.sign_in_count as sign19_58_, inituser0_.updated_by as updated20_58_, inituser0_.updated_date as updated21_58_, inituser0_.username as username58_ from InitUser inituser0_ where inituser0_.enabled=0 and date_add_interval(inituser0_.created_date, 1, day)<now() and (inituser0_.end_date is null)

WARN : org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 1305, SQLState: 42000
ERROR: org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - FUNCTION myDBName.date_add_interval does not exist
ERROR: com.somePackage.InitUserDAOImpl - could not execute query
```

It gets beyond the creation of the query, and then tries to execute it, and then complains it can't find that function.  It specifies the name of my database in the prefix to the database name.

Is this not being registered correctly?  Should I specify myDBName as the database to register?  If so, how?

Or am I way off?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I used Joda for the time calculation and sent it in pre-calculated.  On the one hand, I had to re-do a bunch of code to support this.  On the other, I've been using it ever sense and couldn't be happier.

http://www.joda.org/joda-time/